# Background.js to content.js using Port & Long-lived messaging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've accomplished sending a single message from background.js to content.js using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` but I need to send a lot of messages throughout the extensions lifecycle, therefore I need to open a port and use **long-lived messaging**.

However, I can't find any working examples of opening a port and sending messages/objects between a background.js file and a content.js file. Does anyone have a decent example that works?

I've also run into issues with the following when trying the example in the official docs `"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."`

Any help with a modern working 'long-lived messaging' example between a background.js and content.js file would be much appreciated :D

As requested here is the code I'm currently using that works for single message sending. I'd just like to change this so that I can send lots of messages, not just one.

```
// Content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {           
        if (request.message == 'dataready') {
            //Do something
            sendResponse({});
            return true;   
        }        
    }
);



// Background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {   
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                message: 'dataready',
                action: dataForiFrame
            }, 
            function(response) {

            });  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is without seeing the current code. There are many ways to organize communication depending on the overall workflow of the extension and the examples should be easy to find. As for the "Receiving end" error it means you're connecting when there is no listener on the other side which may happen due to several reasons and again without [MCVE](/help/mcve) it's too vague (maybe your code is wrong or manifest.json is wrong or you didn't reload the tab after reloading the extension).

Comment: hiya.. i can update the above to show the code I'm currently using, however as I've stated that works for sending one message only. I need to send multiple messages. the examples I have found I can't get to work at all, hence why I'm posting here :)

Comment: Have you looked at Chrome's featured [extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/extensions-gallery). They likely have a sample that will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you send hundreds of messages per second there's probably no need to use port-based messaging but let's see how it might look.

Your setup is relatively complicated so you would need to maintain a `Map` of tabId to `port` relations.

#### Handshake initiated in content script

The content script would initiate chrome.runtime.connect, the background script would listen in onConnect and update the mapping. Then tabs.onUpdated listener will use this map to send the message to the right port.

content script:

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'content'});
port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  console.log(msg.data);
  // send a response if needed, may be a simple object/array
  port.postMessage({id: msg.id, data: 'gotcha'}); 
});
```

background script:

```
const portMap = new Map();
const resolveMap = new Map();
let messageId = 0;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    const response = await send(tabId, {message: 'dataready', action: 'foo'});
    console.log(response);
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  portMap.set(port.sender.tab.id, port);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onPortDisconnected);
  port.onMessage.addListener(onPortMessage);
});

function onPortDisconnected(port) {
  portMap.delete(port.sender.tab.id);
}

function onPortMessage(msg, port) {
  resolveMap.get(msg.id)(msg.data);
  resolveMap.delete(msg.id);
}

function send(tabId, data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const id = ++messageId;
    resolveMap.set(id, resolve);
    portMap.get(tabId).postMessage({id, data});
  });
}
```

This is a very barebone example without any error-checking. Also note, it's not the only or the best solution. Depending on other factors that aren't present in the question there could be other solutions.

---

#### Handshake initiated in background script

For example, it's possible to reverse the handshake and call chrome.tabs.connect in the background script to connect to onConnect inside the content script.

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    console.log(msg.data);
    // send a response if needed, may be a simple object/array
    port.postMessage({id: msg.id, data: 'gotcha'}); 
  });
});
```

background script:

```
const portMap = new Map();
const resolveMap = new Map();
let messageId = 0;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    const response = await send(tabId, {message: 'dataready', action: 'foo'});
    console.log(response);
  }
});

function onPortDisconnected(port) {
  portMap.delete(port.sender.tab.id);
}

function onPortMessage(msg, port) {
  resolveMap.get(msg.id)(msg.data);
  resolveMap.delete(msg.id);
}

function send(tabId, data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const id = ++messageId;
    let port = portMap.get(tabId);
    if (!port) {
      port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabId, {frameId: 0});
      port.onDisconnect.addListener(onPortDisconnected);
      port.onMessage.addListener(onPortMessage);
      portMap.set(tabId, port);
    }
    resolveMap.set(id, resolve);
    port.postMessage({id, data});
  });
}
```

P.S. The problem with examples is that people tend to copy them without understanding the mechanics. For instance, your code seems to needlessly use chrome.tabs.query inside onUpdated listener even though it already has `tabId` parameter, thus assuming it's always the active tab that got updated even when it's not so.

Comment: thanks for this @wOxxOm I'll take a proper look at the code tomorrow evening. I use the 'onUpdated listener' to only send the message to the content.js when everything is loaded and ready, otherwise you get the dreaded 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.' problem. I've really not copied and pasted this stuff, its the result of pretty much a half day of attempts :D

Comment: It's still doing the wrong thing in case an inactive tab is updated. That error is not "solved" by this. The error means there was no listener at the moment the message was sent so most likely your content script was running after you were sending the message. You can add `"run_at": "document_start"` in manifest.json or switch to programmatic injection, more info in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: I actually realised I had made a massive mistake and had put the one of the event listeners in a function that was getting called lots of times, therefore making lots of eventlisteners! so, I have it working now with my original script! however, thank you so much for you answer, I will mark it as correct either way :D