# mapping between tab IDs and runtime.Port

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on devtools panel like described here: http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Extending_the_developer_tools.html

I'm trying to send messages to and back from the page(contentScript)
my problem is when the contentScript send the message back to the background process, the background process doesn't know which port to use to forward the msg back to the panel.
I do have a list of all the ports, but I can find a way to associate a panelPort to a tab ID.

The previous document says:
"The background page can then maintain a mapping between tab IDs and runtime.Port objects, and use this to route messages between the two scopes."
Any idea how to acheve this mapping?

- when my panel connects the background, I get the panelPort, but I can't pass any information about the tabId
- when my panel send the tabId via message to the background, I can find what panelPort was used for this message.

Thanks for your help

Comment: See [Background.js to content.js using Port & Long-lived messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600254). There may be other/better examples.

Comment: I'm afraid, this exemple doesn't work for devtools extensions. It only works for simple background > contentScript plugin. My devtools extension send message from panel > background > contentScript

Comment: When you connect the port you can send the tab id as chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'panel:' + chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId}) and in your background script your onConnect listener will extract this id from `port.name`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that should work. I was trying to see if there is a more 'cleaner' solution. But I can't find any.