# How to pass message from background to devtools panel page in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

### Problem

My devtools panel cannot get message from background.
I've tried two forms of message passing.

### Code

#### background.js

```js
export const devtoolsPort = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'devtools' });

// 1
devtoolsPort.postMessage(message);
// 2
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message);
```

#### panel.js (devtools panel)

```js
devtoolsPort.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  console.log('1-1', message);
});
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
  port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    console.log('1-2', message);
  });
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  console.log('2-1', message);
});
```

but none of the `console.log` runs

### Errors

#### background

[image]

#### devtools panel

[image]

Comment: You need to reverse the direction - call connect in panel.js - because the background script starts independently of devtools and it can happen when devtools is closed.

Comment: But I need to implement listening for the content of the web page. My idea is that the content gets modified and forwarded to the panel through the background

Comment: so I need to make listener in devtools not background

Comment: Since it won't connect, you can't. Normally the background script only listens and relays the messages from the content to devtools. There could be also a different method, so please show/describe what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: Sure.Thanks a lot! This is my flow:

1. website send message by `window.postMessage` to content.

2. content use **Long-lived connections** to pass message to background.

3. background send message to panel.js.

I need to implement 3 now, but the above problem occurs.

Comment: You can use a map for ports keyed on tab id, here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600254), you can also inspect the code of other devtools extensions as this workflow is quite typical.

Comment: I think my main problem is to add a listener to the `panel` to get the `background` message. Is it possible for me to achieve this effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245986/discussion-between-jsun969-and-woxxom).